# How to create a recursive relationship using Realm?

Tags: java, android, realm

Model:

```
public class Dog extends RealmObject {
  @PrimaryKey
  public String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
  ... other random String attributes
  public Dog mother;
}
```

Activity:

```
public class CustomActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  private Realm realm;
  private Dog dog = new Dog();

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    realm.close();
  }

  private void setMother(int id) {
   dog.mother = realm.where(Dog.class).equalTo(ID, id).findFirst();
  }

  private void saveDog() {
   realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
      @Override
      public void execute(Realm realm) {
        realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(dog);
      }
    });
  }

}
```

When I run this code it gave me this error:

`Objects which belong to Realm instances in other threads cannot be copied into this Realm instance.`

The only way I got it working is by using realm.copyFromRealm() but the whole object is copied and I don't want that.

Should I save the mother Id alone and query the mother wherever I need it later in my app ?

Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do without copying the whole object ?

---

EDIT:

I originally thought that the whole object was copied using realm.copyFromRealm() because of the way it looks in realm browser.
I just tested to update a field in dog.mother and it updates the linked object which means that it is not a copy.
I still don't know if it is the best way or the correct way to achieve what I m trying to do but it does what I wanted.

Comment: The answer to this question will depend if the mother is already in Realm or not and how you want it to update. You can just create a full in-memory representation of your graph and do `copyToRealmOrUpdate` on all of it, but that might not be what you want.

Comment: The mother will always be in Realm first. 
I'm sorry but I'm not sure to understand what you mean by '_create a full in-memory representation of your graph and do copyToRealmOrUpdate_ ' . Isn't what I'm doing in my example ? My final goal is to create a link just by getting a reference to the mother. I currently do it like that:
    `dog.mother = realm.copyFromRealm(realm.where(Dog.class).equalTo(ID, id).findFirst());`   

 Is it ok to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  private Realm realm;    

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance(); //<--- this is on ui thread
```

---

```
realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
  @Override
  public void execute(Realm realm) {
    realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(dog);  // <-- this is on background thread
  //...


private void setMother(int id) {
   dog.mother = realm.where(Dog.class).equalTo(ID, id).findFirst(); // <-- uses UI-thread Realm stored as field
```

---

So if you use `setMother()` on background thread, you'll access the UI thread Realm and it'll throw IllegalStateException.

You need to pass Realm for the given thread to the method.

```
  private void setMother(Realm realm, Dog dog, int id) {
   dog.mother = realm.where(Dog.class).equalTo(ID, id).findFirst();
  }

  private void saveDog() {
   realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
      @Override
      public void execute(Realm realm) {
        Dog _dog = realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(dog);
        setMother(realm, _dog, id);
      }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it really helps me understand what was my error. One more things, let say I want to display a preview of some mother's attributes until the user press the save button. Should I query the mother once and link it to my new dog with copyFromRealm or query the mother where I want to display it (without linking it the new dog) and then make a second query when the user decide to save ? What would be the best practice here ?

Comment: `query the mother where I want to display it (without linking it the new dog) and then make a second query when the user decide to save ?` sounds right

Answer (score 1):

Your exception happens because you construct the `Dog` object on the UI thread and then passes it off to the async worker thread, but that means you also passed the reference to the `mother` which isn't allowed. Instead, you need to do the setup in the async method like this:

```
private void saveDog() {
    realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
      @Override
      public void execute(Realm realm) {
        // This will give you mother reference on the correct thread
        setMother(motherId, dog);
        realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(dog);
      }
    });
}
```